# Freeing up memory with free function causing my program to crash

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

I could use some help with my program, 
I wrote a program that is counting the number of anagrams in a sentence, for which I am using a `malloc()` function, you can see in my code `**ArrPtr=malloc`.

I use this to count the anagrams, after finishing it I want to continue to my second part of the program and I wish to free the memory with `free(arrPtr);`
and the program crashes (It didn't crash when I did not use the free option).

Here's my code,

```
void main()
{
    char str[1001] = { 0 };
    char temp[1001] = { 0 }, temp2;
    char strB[1001] = { 0 };
    int printf_i, counter, i, q, flag, j = 1, r = 0, m = 1, length = 0, root = 0, m1 = 0;
    int max_analogy = 0, counter2 = 0, O, sum, sum2;
    char **arrPtr;
    int k = 0;
    int **matrix;

    printf("Please enter the sentence, and then press Enter:\n");
    gets(str);

    //bubble sort
    strcpy_s(strB, 1001, str);
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(strB); i = q + 2)
    {
        do
        {
            flag = 0;
            for (q = i; strB[q + 1] != 32 && strB[q + 1] != 0; q++)
            {
                if (strB[q] > strB[q + 1])
                {
                    // Swap
                    temp2 = strB[q];
                    strB[q] = strB[q + 1];
                    strB[q + 1] = temp2;
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
        } while (flag != 0);
    }
    counter = 1;
    length = strlen(strB);

    for (i = 0; strB[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        if (strB[i] == 32)
        {
            strB[i] = 0;
            counter++;
        }
    }

    arrPtr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*counter);
    arrPtr[0] = strB;
    q = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (strB[i] == 0)
        {
            arrPtr[q] = &strB[i + 1];
            q++;
        }
    }

    counter2 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        for (q = i + 1; q < counter; q++)
        {
            if (arrPtr[q] == 0 || arrPtr[i] == 0)
                continue;
            if (!strcmp(arrPtr[q], arrPtr[i]))
            {
                counter2++;
                arrPtr[q] = 0;
            }
        }
        if (max_analogy < counter2)
            max_analogy = counter2;
        counter2 = 0;
    }
    printf("The maximum number of anagram words in this sentence is %d.\n", max_analogy);

    free(arrPtr);
}
```

Comment: You are writing more than allocated for `arrPtr`.

Answer (score 1):

```
arrPtr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*counter);
```

is wrong fo many reason:

1. `arrPtr` is `(char **)`.
2. cast using a C compiler is useless and dangerous.
3. you must allocate `sizeof(char *)`

reason 3 is the real reason of you problem: you are allocating `counter` bytes while you write `counter*sizeof(char *)` (most probably `counter*8`), so you are writing out of bounds of allocated memory corrupting `malloc` memory pool.

---

You can fix it using

```
arrPtr = malloc(sizeof(char *)*counter);
```